# Component Not Showing in View

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created a new child route called `users` as shown below for my side panel.

When i run `npm start`, and click on the users, nothing appears in the view even though the path shows `/app/account/user`. What could i be doing wrong ?

PS: I copied the content of `/app/account/manager` to `/app/account/user`

```
item: [
      {
         "menu_title": "sidebar.uiComponents",
         "menu_icon": "zmdi zmdi-wrench",
         "type_multi": null,
         "new_item": false,
         "child_routes": [
            {
               "path": "/app/account/manager",
               "new_item": false,
               "menu_title": "sidebar.manager"
             },
              {
               "path": "/app/account/user",
               "new_item": false,
               "menu_title": "sidebar.user"
             }

]
```

Comment: is mangers works ?

Comment: @AshishKamble, yes It does work fine

Comment: are you using `react-router` `<switch> <route>` thing